# Material UI, ListItem child onClick listener, triggers the parent onClick too

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the [List component of MUI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/#interactive) when I click a child component of ListItem (in this case the delete iconButton) the onClick callback of the ListItem it self is also triggered.

in the below example if I click the `delete` button beside the `handleDelete` the parent onClick callback (`handleNavigate` ) is also triggered. The same is for `handleValidate` of the `avatar`

Why is it so, and how to prevent it?

```
        <List>
            <ListItem
              onClick={handleNavigate}
              secondaryAction={
                <IconButton edge="end" aria-label="delete" onClick={handleDelete}>
                  <DeleteIcon />
                </IconButton>
              }
            >
              <ListItemAvatar onClick={handleValidate}>
                <Avatar>
                  <FolderIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </ListItemAvatar>
              <ListItemText
                primary="Single-line item"
              />
            </ListItem>
        </List>
```

Comment: Try to add `event.stopPropagation()` in you `handleValidate` see the [MDN dcos about stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `Event.stopPropagation()`

```
const handleDelete = (ev) => { 
   ev.stopPropagation()

   // rest of the code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, react libraries have become so rich, where it was a long time I have not worked with HTML events  :))